# Get ls to always show the modified time in hours/minutes

Tags: unix

How can I get the **ls** command to show an exact time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might depend on your distro, but this argument for `ls` is available in Debian:

```
--time-style=STYLE
          with -l, show times using style STYLE: full-iso, long-iso,  iso,
          locale,  +FORMAT.   FORMAT is interpreted like `date'; if FORMAT
          is FORMAT1<newline>FORMAT2, FORMAT1 applies to non-recent  files
          and FORMAT2 to recent files; if STYLE is prefixed with `posix-',
          STYLE takes effect only outside the POSIX locale
```

try

```
man ls
```

from your command line

Comment: `--time-style` and `--full-time` are specific to GNU ls, so they're available on every Linux (except some embedded distributions) and few other unices.

Comment: @Gilles, moreover, `--time-style` is absent in busybox, `--full-time` in this sense better to use.

Answer (score 7):

As well as CaseyIT's solution, you can also use the `--full-time` option.

Answer (score 1):

Your locale will affect the way `ls` displays that date and time.

My locale is `en_US.UTF-8` and `ls` always displays hours and minutes when I use `ls -l`, for example. However, if I change my locale like this:

```
LC_TIME=C ls -l
```

files that are newer than six months old don't show a year, older than six months or are in the future don't display a time at all and do show the year. The `C` locale (aka the `POSIX` locale) reproduces the historical behavior of `ls` in this regard (I seem to recall that there were some additional subtleties, however).

Answer (score 1):

In FreeBSD the -T flag does this

`ls -alFT`

`-rwxrwxr-x   1 un  un  4900 May  5 10:52:03 2013 custom-banner.js*`

Comment: Helpful for `macOS`'s `ls`.